# Cannot access Android's Internal storage on Android 10+

Tags: android, local-storage, android-storage, android-internal-storage

I try to read a zip file from Internal Storage's root folder. For this I use the below code snippet:

`val zipFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "audio_book.zip"`

The file is available in desired path. In logcat I can see that it has found the file

> 2020-08-09 12:00:27.315 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook I/(AudioBookRepo.kt:66)#readFileFromStorage [ RidmikLog:  ]: zipFile: /storage/emulated/0/audio_book.zip

But then it throws `FileNotFoundException` and says Permission Denied:

```
2020-08-09 12:00:27.343 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/audio_book.zip (Permission denied)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.343 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.343 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:265)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.343 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:187)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.343 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:201)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.343 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at com.ridmik.app.audio_book.utils.ZipUtilKt.unzip(ZipUtil.kt:30)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.343 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at com.ridmik.app.audio_book.utils.ZipUtilKt.unzip$default(ZipUtil.kt:14)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.343 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at com.ridmik.app.audio_book.repo.AudioBookRepo.readFileFromStorage(AudioBookRepo.kt:69)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.343 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at com.ridmik.app.audio_book.repo.AudioBookRepo.populateDatabase(AudioBookRepo.kt:34)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.343 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at com.ridmik.app.audio_book.repo.AudioBookRepo$populateDatabase$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:12)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.343 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.343 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.344 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.344 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.344 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.344 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.344 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.344 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
2020-08-09 12:00:27.344 10736-10736/audiobookapplication.audiobook W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

**PS: Storage permission has been taken and declared in Manifest and this code works below Android 10**

I tried using following in my manifest file under `<application` tag. Doesn't work.

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

How can I solve this for Android 10+ ?

Comment: And request legacy should do the trick.

Comment: @blackapps It did not. I mentioned that in the post. Is there alternative way?

Comment: It does the trick for Android Q. How did you manage to place that zip file there?

Comment: `Storage permission has been taken` What do you mean by that?

Comment: @blackapps I took permission by requesting permission at runtime to read and write storage. And by putting following in manifest: 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

And the Zip file has been placed manually for testing purpose now. It will come from server later.